# Convert a string to an integral number?

Tags: c

How is this even possible? One of my textbook questions (studying for an exam here) claim you can do this and ask the following:

Write a function that accepts a string. The function should convert the string to an integral number. If it cannot convert return 0.

Example 1: 8976 returns the value of 
`((((8*10 + 9) *10)+ 7 )* 10) + 6`

Example 2: 67A returns a value of 0

How can this be done? I know you can use the `atoi()` function but the book wants this to be done without any functions?

Edit: Some further thinking:

```
 int i, ans;
 char number[5]="8976";

 for(i=0;i<strlen(number);i++)
   ans=(ans*10)+(number[i]-'0');
```

Would the above work?

Comment: "How is this even possible?" - [Maths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  There are many functions to do this, including: `atoi()`; `strtol()` et al; `sscanf()`; etc.

Comment: Example 1 pretty much tells you how to do it. What remains is to check whether a character is a digit (and handling signs), and check for overflows. In response to your edit: Very close. The checks are still missing. And you haven't initialised `ans`.

Comment: This question and the edits make out a perfect example of the fact that "just a spoonful of thinking and the medicine goes down"...

Comment: You need to set `ans = 0` before you start using it; you probably need to validate that `number[i]` is a digit.  Otherwise, it is about right, though it has no error checking for overflows, negative numbers, explicitly positive numbers (+123), etc.  You don't report an error (set `ans` to zero) for `67A`.  And using `strlen()` in the loop like that is sub-optimal; the string length does not change, so add `int len = strlen(number);` and compare with `len` instead of `strlen(number)` in the loop.

Comment: @ H2CO3 what do you mean by the medicine goes down? and sorry if I was being a bit superfluous with "how is this even possible." I am starting out with this stuff and this question surprised me.

Comment: *Hint* the source for all standard C functions is readily available, Google to see how they're implemented

Comment: @user2517940 [Reference to the classic song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8VHc49ZdP4) :P Anyways, I meant that it requires only a small amount of effort and a few moments of thinking and any reasonably intelligent person can find out the solution easily.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler for the checking if number is a digit bit would a loop comparing each index of number to the ascii values for non numbers suffice? then using an if else statement to either return 0 or the digit

Comment: Better to use `#include <ctype.h>` and `isdigit((unsigned char)number[i])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was writing something but in the meantime the question was basically answered, in the OP edits and further comments.

Here is the function header:

```
int f(const char *str)
{
```

The variables: **v** is the computed value, **c** is a pointer to the current character being scanned, **d** is the value of the current digit.

```
    int v;
    const char *c;
    int d;

    v = 0;
    c = str;
```

Iteration will stop on the null terminator, when **c** points to **0**, which is **FALSE** in C. Scanning is left to right.

```
    while (*c)
    {
```

The OP got the main idea right.

```
        v *= 10;
        d = *c - '0';
```

You should just test **d** to check that it is between **0** and **9**.

```
        if (d < 0 || d > 9)
            return 0;
```

This solution uses pointers in place of indices.

```
        v += d;
        ++c;
    }
```

Return the result.

```
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Correctly formatted code. Rare bird on SO. Anyway, I'd suggest making the argument `const`-correct.

Comment: @darnix911 Perfect, thanks. Also good point with the pointer arithmetic instead of an explicit length and loop counter.

Comment: @user2517940: In case you just started programming, it is a good investment in my opinion to use **return** (and also **break** and **continue**) parsimoniously that is, ideally, only one time at the end of the function. Try to rewrite the function in my answer in a way that it uses a single **return v;** at the end.

Comment: @darnix911 Not needed, in general. Really not an issue with such a simple function.

Comment: @H2CO3: Thanks, in C++ I never forget **const**, in C often I do. It must be a trauma from childhood, caused by some esoteric C compiler that didn't support that keyword :-)

Comment: Yes, it's very pedantic for such simple function, and I'm pretty sure you would never see the enforcement of a *single return rule* in a real project.

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there, your code isn't bad just missing a declaration and an if

```
int main()
{
    int i, ans;
    ans=0;
    char number[5]="12";

    for(i=0;i<strlen(number);i++){
        if( !(number[i]>='0' && number[i]<='9')  ){
            ans = 0;
            break;
        }
        ans=(ans*10)+(number[i]-'0');
    }

    printf("%d\n",ans);

    return 0;
}
```

you can also check the code here:
http://cfiddle.net/cvYCYB